# is there a simpler way to generate random password

Tags: python, list, if-statement, import, generator

```
import string
import random
characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()")

i = input('Please enter confirm (input 1) to proceed with password creation (or any to quit):\n')
if i == 1:
  print("Generating username and password....") 
  length = int(input("Enter password length: "))
  random.shuffle(characters)


  password = []
  for i in range(length):
    password.append(random.choice(characters))


  random.shuffle(password)



  print("".join(password))

else:
   exit
```

Is there a simpler way to generate a random password, also generating a password doesn't work in the if statement how do i fix this. I also want to be able to call out my password so how do i put it in a variable after ive generated one.

Comment: `input` always returns a string.  Do `if i == '1':`.

Comment: Skip the loop and do `password = characters[:length]`.  And you don't need the second shuffle.

Comment: Yes.  `uuid.uuid4().hex`  Guaranteed to be unique and strong enough for cryptographic use.

Comment: Well, that only uses the alphabet of hex digits.

Comment: @TimRoberts - True.  Yet, meets the stated requirement of “Is there a simpler way to generate random password”.

Comment: Is confirmation really necessary?  If the user didn't want a password, they wouldn't have run your script, and running the script only prints a password to standard output, rather than overwriting a file somewhere (ignoring output redirection).

Comment: `password = ''.join(random.choices(characters, k=length))`. Shuffling a list of random characters doesn't make it any more random.

Comment: last else is pretty pointless but if u want to keep it, make it `else: exit()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your method as a function, so you can do whatever you want with the return value:

```
import string
import random

characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()")

def genpassword(length):
    random.shuffle(characters)
    return ''.join(characters[:length])

length = int(input("Enter password length: "))
print("Generating username and password....") 
password = genpassword(length)
print(password)
```

The `random.choices` option mentioned in the comments is a better implementation.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Taking a prefix of the shuffled alphabet generates a poor password, as it eliminates any password that duplicates a character as a possibility,

Comment: Agreed, and the OP should keep that in mind.  I wanted to show something that used his concept in a better envelope.

Comment: `password = "".join([random.choice(characters) for _ in range(lenght)])`

Comment: @PedroMaia really then just use `password = ''.join(random.choices(characters, k=length))`